# Linking business model with technical model

Tags: business-process-management

We use ARIS Business Architect for modelling business process and Sparx Enterprise Architect for technical models like sequence diagrams, component diagrams etc.  Is there a way to link the technical models designed using  EA from ARIS business process, so that it would be easy to trace the business function end to end.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Aris has the ability export their models in XMI format - which means you should be able to import them (to some degree, into Enterprise Architect). Keeping in mind that there is no one true flavor of XMI that crosses between all tools, so it might get you close.

Failing that Enterprise Architect is able to store hyperlinks in its diagrams / repositories to launch other files from, so you could use Enterprise Architects traceability capability from the technical models up to a reference to the business processes which then link out to Aris at the click of a button.

I understand this is an older question, but hopefully it helps none the less.